# "could not find function" when using functions as arguments

Tags: r, pointers, function-pointers

I have two .R files, plotDataSet(..) and plotAllDataSets(). plotDataSet(..) makes a call to curve(..) (in the R graphics library), while plotAllDataSets() makes a call to plotDataSet(..). plotDataSet(..) takes a function as a parameter, and passes it to curve(..).

I want to pass in my function argument for curve(..) into plotDataSet(..) from a list of functions, such as:

```
 v <- c(function(x){x}, function(x){x*x}, function(x){x*x}, function(x){x*x*x}, 
     function(x){x*x}, function(x){x*x*x}, function(x){x*x*x})
for (i in 1:7) {
    plotSaveData(data, v[i], i)
}
```

I get the following output: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "expectedOrderEquation"`.

Interestingly, when I call plotDataSet(..) and pass in a function like `function(x){x*x}`, it works fine:

```
for (i in 1:7) {
    plotSaveData(data, function(x) {x}, i)
}
```

But this won't let me call plotSaveData(..) while cycling through a list of functions.

Can someone please explain why this does not work?

I hope this is sufficient, but I am happy to provide more context as needed. Also, I am a bit new to R, so any corrections to my descriptions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use double brackets instead of single brackets

```
v[[i]]   instead of v[i]
```

Have a look at the difference between these two:

```
v[[i]] (3)  
v[i] (3) # error
```

The single brackets returns a list, whose contents is a function
The double brackets returns the function.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft and so will  `v[i][1][1][1][[1]](x)`  ;)